# Debian raspberry pi crashes when writing to SD-card

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, sd-card

So after a day of having my pi crash when doing apt-get upgrade and wget i reinstalled debian only to find that the problem remained on the clean system. i did a badblocks read-only test which showed no bad sectors. I then ran

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=50 conv=fdatasync
```

i found out that the system crashes reliably when the size of the write-file is above 50 Mb. it also crashes sometimes when below. The following is the result of some of the output. (the system crashes after the 50 Mb write-test).

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=30 conv=fdatasync
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB) copied, 2.12823 s, 14.8 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=30 conv=fdatasync
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB) copied, 2.12079 s, 14.8 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=40 conv=fdatasync
40+0 records in
40+0 records out
41943040 bytes (42 MB) copied, 3.00369 s, 14.0 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=45 conv=fdatasync
45+0 records in
45+0 records out
47185920 bytes (47 MB) copied, 3.17322 s, 14.9 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=50 conv=fdatasync
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: I read about problems with the raspberry pi and specific sd-cards depending on the country where the pi has been produced (UK or China). You should find more detailed information about this issue when searching for it.

Comment: I have actually used the very same card succesfully for quite some time. I just messed the system up and reinstalled the fresh distro on the card via win32imager

Answer (score 2):

Setting Overclock to None fixed that for me.

`raspi-config -> Overclock -> None` and reboot.

I have a SanDisk SDHC 16GB Class 10 Ultra(30MB/s).